# Time since Windows 7 was last unlocked

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to determine the time since a Windows 7 machine was last unlocked. By unlocked I mean the user locks the machine by clicking Start->ShutDown->Lock or by pressing the Windows key + L, and then at a later time unlocks the machine by clicking on the user icon (and depending on settings typing in password)?

Comment: I know you can set auditing for logon/logoff, but I can't seem to find any policy to log when you unlock the machine.  Hmm...maybe somebody will know how to find such a thing, but I'd expect to find it in Group Policy Editor and it's just Not Here™.  Out of curiosity (and possibly finding a different solution that meets your goals), what's the goal here?

Comment: The rather innocuous task of determining when I started work. I rarely log off, but always lock in the evening and then unlock in the morning.

Comment: Hmm...there's probably software that will do something similar (not necessarily logging the unlock event, but just mouse/keyboard activity or something), but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Open **Event Viewer**, browse to **Windows Logs** > **Security** and look for an event with ID 4624:

[image: Details for event 4624]

*Logon Type: 7* indicates a workstation unlock.

Comment: I am spammed with events with that ID. Which one should I look for?

Comment: @AndersLindén The one with Logon Type: 7

Answer (score 4):

To show *only* Workstation Unlock events (i.e. Logon Type: 7):

1. Open Event Viewer.
2. In the right pane, click "Create Custom View".
3. Click the "XML" tab.
4. Check "Edit query manually".
5. Click "Yes" at the confirmation box.
6. Paste in this XML:

   ```
   <QueryList>
     <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
       <Select Path="Security">
         *[
           EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType']='7']
           and
           System[(EventID='4624')]
           and
           System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]] <!-- Show only events in the last seven days -->
         ] 
       </Select>
     </Query>
   </QueryList>
   ```
7. Click OK.
8. Enter a name and description, e.g. "Unlock times", "Times when a user unlocked the computer".
9. Click OK.
10. Now, whenever you want to know the time you unlocked the computer, open the "Custom Views" folder in the left pane and select "Unlock times" (or whatever you named the filter in Step 8).

Source: [Filtering Security Logs by User and Logon Type](https://serverfault.com/a/571977)

[image: Screenshot of XML tab in Custom View Properties dialog of Event Viewer]

Answer (score 2):

Powershell 6 one-liner (run as administrator):

```
(get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4624;'LogonType'='7'}  -MaxEvents 1).TimeCreated
```

Earlier versions of Powershell:

```
(Get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{logname='security'; id=4624; starttime=(get-date).date} | where {$_.properties[8].value -eq 7})[0].TimeCreated
```