# Get the total logged-in time period on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I wanted to get the total time period during a day in which I am logged-in to my PC.

The assumption is that if my PC is locked, I am away from the PC. This will give me the total numbers of hours spent in front of the PC.

**Update** : Please note I am not looking for the uptime or time the computer is running. I am interested in how long I am working on the PC.And it is not answered in the link tagged above.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/326940/time-since-windows-7-was-last-unlocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WMI

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set sessions = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("select * from Win32_Session")

For Each objSession in sessions
   Wscript.Echo objSession.StartTime
Next
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578/determining-how-long-the-user-is-logged-on-to-windows)

Comment: Hi Dave, is there a way to get the time when the PC is last locked and unlocked from the Win32_Session ??

Comment: @KunalJha  Yes... In Event Viewer, under the Security section.